# What kind of ISO 27k certifications can an individual get?

Tags: certification, iso27001

I heard that there are ISO 27K certifications. E.G. Info Security foundation based on ISO/IEC 27002. I am interested how it is possible to get a higher level, what kind of options there are to get iso 27k certifications, what are the steps?

Thanks and regards

Comment: This is one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27001_Lead_Auditor

Answer (score 1):

An individual cannot be certified to ISO 27001. It is a management system standard for organisations. An individual could become an ISO 27001 lead auditor or and ISO 27001 lead implementer.